# How to draw WPF Adorners on top of everything else?

Tags: wpf, z-order, adorner, adornerdecorator

I've added an Adorner to my [DateTimePicker control](https://gist.github.com/1150228) but it's not shown on top of the other controls. Why? How do I fix it?

[image: My adorner]

My XAML currently goes like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="IntelliMap.WPF.DateTimePicker"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:wpftc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    ...
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <Grid>
            ...
            <TextBox x:Name="DateDisplay" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ...>
            </TextBox>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</UserControl>
```

The adorner itself is a separate class from the UserControl and added in the constructor:

```
public DateTimePicker()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...

    AdornerLayer adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(DateDisplay);
    if (adornerLayer != null)
    {
        adornerLayer.Add(_upDownBtns = new TextBoxUpDownAdorner(DateDisplay));
        _upDownBtns.Click += (textBox, direction) => { OnUpDown(direction); };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem apparently occurs because the Adorners governed by the `AdornerDecorator` are only guaranteed to appear on top of the controls inside the AdornerDecorator. It is necessary to wrap most of the contents of the window in an AdornerDecorator instead, but after doing this, `AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer()` apprently can't see the AdornerDecorator under some circumstances and returns null.

The documentation claims "GetAdornerLayer walks up the visual tree, starting at the specified `UIElement`, and returns the first adorner layer it finds." In reality, `GetAdornerLayer` cannot find an `AdornerDecorator` located outside of the `UserControl`, at least not in .NET 3.5. I fixed the problem by doing exactly what `GetAdornerLayer` claims to do itself:

```
static AdornerLayer GetAdornerLayer(FrameworkElement subject)
{
    AdornerLayer layer = null;
    do {
        if ((layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(subject)) != null)
            break;
    } while ((subject = subject.Parent as FrameworkElement) != null);
    return layer;
}
public DateTimePicker()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        // not null anymore!
        AdornerLayer adLayer = GetAdornerLayer(DateDisplay);
    };
}
```

Finally, `GetAdornerLayer` must be called from the `Loaded` event instead of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There's already an adorner layer in the default Window style, and that adorner layer sits above the content of the window.

So just remove the AdornerLayer from the UserControl and that should work.

Comment: The `AdornerDecorator` is there because without it, `GetAdornerLayer` returns null.

Comment: Ah, do the adorner setup in the activate event of your control, instead of the constructor. The control needs to be on screen before GetAdornerLayer can get the windows AdornerLayer.

Comment: What event? There's no Activate event on UserControl. I tried `Loaded`, but `GetAdornerLayer` still returns null in that event.

Comment: In a usercontrol, override `ApplyTemplate`.

Comment: Here is a [question that has a solution to get the window adorner decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595243/in-wpf-how-to-display-adornerlayer-on-top-of-datagrid)