# Expand cell with number span in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` and when someone clicks on a DataGridCell I want values to overlay that cell. What is the best way to do about this? Adornlayer? Custom Control?

Below is an example. Someone clicks on `17.27` of a DataGrid and I want to have the ranges of the price next to it. The user can then choose a value and set the DataGridCell with the new price. A twist is that the values are next to, not a drop down or I can just use a `ComboBox`.

[image]

Comment: What is your current code like? What have you tried?

Comment: I just learned about adornerlayer and wondering if I am over thinking this. This just seem complicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595243/in-wpf-how-to-display-adornerlayer-on-top-of-datagrid I was going to do dropdown, but my user says he wants the prices to the right of the selected cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me for you will fit this controls:

---

- [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx)

[image]

For the `ComboBox` you can set the dynamic range, being attached to the collection. In `DataGrid` you can do yourself the ComboBox using `DataGridTemplateColumn` column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CustomObjectStringMember}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomObjectListMember}"
                      Text="{Binding Path=CustomObjectStringMember}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Or using`DataGridComboBoxColumn`:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Current Category"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=CurrentCategory}"
                        SelectedValuePath="CategoryID"
                        DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource categoriesDataProvider}}" />
```

---

- [`IntegerUpDown`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntegerUpDown)

[image]

`IntegerUpDown` provides a TextBox with button spinners that allow incrementing and decrementing Nullable values by using the spinner buttons.

---

- [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.110).aspx) + [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx)

Try using `Popup` with `ListBox` like this:

```
<Popup Name="MyPopUp"
       UseLayoutRounding="True"
       AllowsTransparency="False"
       IsOpen="True"
       Placement="Right">

    <Border Name="BorderContent" 
            UseLayoutRounding="True"
            Width="140"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="Black">

        <StackPanel Background="White">
            <TextBlock Background="White" 
                       Foreground="Black"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="MARKET" />

            <Separator Background="Black" Height="2" />

            <ListBox BorderBrush="Transparent">
                <ListBoxItem>17.27</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>17.28</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>17.29</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>17.30</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

`Output`

[image]

For `Popup` you can set Placement to *`Right`* and use dynamic collection for ItemSource. To appear the Popup in the `DataGrid` you need place it in the `CellEditingTemplate` like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Sample}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Sample}" />
                <Popup ... />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: This would work, but my users want the box next to the item, not as a drop down.

Comment: Error: DataTemplate already has a child and cannot add popup datatemplate

Comment: @kay00: Add panel in DataTemplate: `<DataTemplate><Grid><TextBox/><Popup/></Grid>`. See my example carefully.

Comment: Popup won't show up when there's binding. For example Text="{Binding Path=Sample}" needs to be replaced with Text=Foo. Also when I choose a value it doesn't set that value for the cell. It is highlighted though.

Comment: My mistake. The popup does show up. But how do I set the value of the cell once I choose a value?

Comment: @kay00: First, you need to necessarily to bind a `SelectedItem` property to ListBox, to know which item has been selected. Second, try using [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380(v=vs.110).aspx) for Binding like this (TextBlock in `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> --> <DataTemplate>`): `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference MyListBoxInPopup}}" ... />`.

Comment: I think the problem is the popup list doesn't know about the datacontext      <ListBox BorderBrush="Transparent" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"> ---><in output window>  System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :
 BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedItem' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=277915782)'. 
 BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem; 
 DataItem='String' (HashCode=277915782); 
 target element is 'ListBox' (Name=''); 
 target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')

Comment: i'll run snoop to see what is going on

Answer (score 0):

I think [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018.aspx) is probably best for this.